# Recording microphone output and playing it without saving

Tags: vb.net, winforms, microphone, recording

I need a start point. How do I record the microphone sound then play it 0.5 seconds later without saving it? Like when you record and you hear yourself after 0.5 seconds.

Comment: What type of application are you working with?  WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, Phone?

Comment: @Walt Ritscher I'm working with WinForms